Configure Login Azure B2C in web app on .NET 8 | 9
I'm trying to configure and also start my .NET 9 web app to use Azure B2C, but I always get the following error

IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from:
InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from:
https://xxxxx.b2clogin.com/xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_signup_signin/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration

When I consult that URL from the browser it works without problems, but when I start the application it gives me the error mentioned.
As much as I read the Microsoft documentation I can't find what the error could be, I'm trying to test this on localhost.
Below I leave the configuration that according to the documentation should be in the Program.cs file
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options => {
    options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Index");
}).AddMvcOptions(options => { })
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

This is my appsettings.json:
"AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.b2clogin.com/",
    "ClientId": "d78aeeba-7ba7-4e99-8233-3dfc5a022d79",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "Domain": "xxxxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout-callback-oidc",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_signup_signin",
    "ResetPassworPolicyId": "B2C_1_passwordreset",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": "B2C_1_editprofile",
    "ClientSecret": "yyyyy~xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}

Tech stack:

Visual Studio 2022
.NET 9 or .NET 8

I tested the user flows in the Azure Portal and they work well.
Thanks

Please Provide image of redirect Uri in App Registration.


IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from:
InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from:
InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from:  https://xxxxx.b2clogin.com/xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_signup_signin/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration

The Error you're facing is due to an incorrect policy name, Domain or instance that you define in appsetting.json.
I created sample Asp. net core MVC using .net 9 and configured authentication with Azure AD B2C.
While creating the app I have selected Authentication Type as Microsoft Identity Platform and update the NuGet packages to latest versions.

Below is my Program.cs file.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
}); 
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
var app = builder.Build();
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapStaticAssets();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}")
    .WithStaticAssets();
app.MapRazorPages()
   .WithStaticAssets();
app.Run();

Make sure to define correct values in the appsettings.json file.
appsettings.json:
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://{ Azure B2C Domain Name}.b2clogin.com/",
  "Domain": "{ Azure B2C Domain Name}.onmicrosoft.com",
  "TenantId": "<TenantID>",
  "ClientId": "<ClientId>",
  "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
  "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_signup_signin",
  "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout-callback-oidc",
  "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "",
  "EditProfilePolicyId": "",
  "ClientSecret": "<ClientSecret>",
  "EnablePiiLogging": true
}

Check if you are using correct User flow name in the appsettings.json.

Output:



@Sebastian Pareja Atencia Please check if the solution above helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.
